# How to refine code in visual c#?

Tags: c#

recently I have seen this code

```
        arrMove                         = new List<int[]>(4);
        m_pppiCaseMoveDiagLine          = new int[64][][];
        m_pppiCaseMoveDiagonal          = new int[64][][];
        m_pppiCaseMoveLine              = new int[64][][];
        m_ppiCaseMoveKnight             = new int[64][];
        m_ppiCaseMoveKing               = new int[64][];
        m_ppiCaseWhitePawnCanAttackFrom = new int[64][];
        m_ppiCaseBlackPawnCanAttackFrom = new int[64][];
```

but i couldn't know how to make my code look like this one using visual c# 2010 ,do you know any shortcut or tool to do that automatically?.

**EDIT**

i have also another related question, if i want to align declarations like this

```
    private PlayerColorE                m_eNextMoveColor;
    private int[]                       m_piPiecesCount;
    private Random                      m_rnd;
    private int                         m_iAttackedPieces;
```

-it seems that it can't be done using *prductivity power tools* extension-

do you have any idea how to do it?

thanks alot for your help!

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? A way to line up the '=' signs?

Comment: Do you mean with tabs to make the declarations on the right line up?

Comment: @Henk: That's my guess as well.  There may be a plugin for VS that does it, but I usually don't see code formatted like this from an IDE.  Maybe ReSharper?  I've never seen it do that, though.

Comment: exactly, that's what am looking for..

Comment: I use the space-bar for this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might want to take a look at the [Productivity Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef) extension for Visual Studio 2010 and its *Align Assignments* feature.